# How to record speech on ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, electron, text-to-speech, web-audio-api, webspeech-api

Im developing a text-to-speech application using ElectronJS. Im using the Web Speech API to create the speech. I want to record that speech. How could I do it?

I tried tons of code but none worked :(

Comment: “_I tried tons of code but none worked_” What code? We can’t debug code without the code. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to include a [mre] showing what you have done. For more info, check out [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that's possible other than by:

1. Playing the speech and sampling it in again using the microphone or a physical cable between line out and line in.
2. Using a software audio loopback device at the operating system level (e.g. in Windows Sound control panel, if your drivers support it, usually hidden and disabled by default).
3. Using a third-party text-to-speech library instead of the Web Speech API.

https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/1764